# 2 column layout, center alignment, while keeping column background colors full size

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm a bit new to bootstrap, trying to figure out how I can get the purple column to stay center aligned while having the whole left column in a purple color.

[image]

Here's what my code looks like so far:

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="row align-items-center">
  <div class="col col-md-6" style="background-color:#7849b8; height: 100% auto;">
    <div class="headline mt-4 ml-4 mr-4 mb-3">Headline Text Here</div>
    <div class="subline ml-4 mr-4 mb-4">This is Subline text. Ha ahaha<br>Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-md-6 p-0" style="background-color:#AEA9F4;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/490x600" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different approaches you can take. One way is to wrap the column content in its own div and center that using flexbox...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-6 d-flex" style="background-color:#7849b8;">
            <div class="align-self-center">
                <div class="headline mt-4 ml-4 mr-4 mb-3">Headline Text Here</div>
                <div class="subline ml-4 mr-4 mb-4">This is Subline text. Ha ahaha<br>Hello</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-6 p-0" style="background-color:#AEA9F4;">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/490x600" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/IMbHi7jOF6

Comment: In your solution, how would I get the image on the right hand side to center with the text (while also maintaining the full color background)?